# pandas dataset 2 column min and max determine a column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe dt like this

```
             minV   maxV
2008-01-02    NaN    NaN
2008-01-03    NaN    NaN
2008-01-04  37.33    NaN
2008-01-07    NaN  37.71
2008-01-08  36.21    NaN
2008-01-09    NaN    NaN
2008-01-10    NaN  37.70
```

on each row I can have either a minV or a maxV.

I can not have on the same day a value NOT NaN for both minV and maxV. (not possible `2008-01-08  36.21    37.71`)

I want to create another dataframe where only on days that have either a minV or maxV not NaN:

- if it was a day of minV then --> 1000
- if it was a day of maxV then --> -1000
  Something like:

```
             val    
2008-01-04   1000.00   
2008-01-07  -1000.00 
2008-01-08   1000.00 
2008-01-10  -1000.00
```

1000 is a constant

Answer (score 2):

You can use `dropna` with `all` to get rid of any rows that are completely null, then use `np.where` to populate your values conditionally.

```
import numpy as np  
df = df.dropna(how='all')    
df['val'] = np.where(df['minV'].isnull(), -1000,1000)    
print(df[['val']])
```

Output

```
             val
2008-01-04  1000
2008-01-07 -1000
2008-01-08  1000
2008-01-10 -1000
```